# Convert table to aggregated table

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python pandas, and I wanna convert the following dataFrame :

```
     AutomationStatus  TestPriority
0                    Done             4
1                    Done             4
2                    Done             4
3                    Done             4
4                    Done             4
5                    Done             4
6                    Done             4
7                    Done             4
8                    Done             4
9       Will Not Automate             3
10                   Done             4
11  Review for Automation             3
12  Review for Automation             3
13  Review for Automation             3
14  Review for Automation             3
15  Review for Automation             3
16  Review for Automation             3
17  Review for Automation             3
18  Review for Automation             3
19  Review for Automation             3
20  Review for Automation             3
21  Review for Automation             3
22  Review for Automation             3
23  Review for Automation             3
24  Review for Automation             3
25  Review for Automation             3
26  Review for Automation             3
27  Review for Automation             3
```

to a format where it shows aggregate numbers for AutomationStatus like this:

```
            TestPriority
                3   4

Automated       0    10
Manual Test     16    2
```

Basically I want to mark `AutomationStatus=Done` as `Automated` and everything els as `Manual Test` and show number of related tests (with priority)

I think I should use `pivot_table` but not an expert.

any suggestion (and pointing to documentation) would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` to align your `AutomationStatus` values.

Then use `pd.pivot_table`. This is a minimal example:

```
print(df)

      AutomationStatus  TestPriority
0                 Done             4
1                 Done             4
2                 Done             4
3      WillNotAutomate             3
4                 Done             4
5  ReviewforAutomation             3
6  ReviewforAutomation             3
7  ReviewforAutomation             3

df['AutomationStatus'] = np.where(df['AutomationStatus'] == 'Done',
                                  'Automated', 'ManualTest')

res = df.pivot_table(index='AutomationStatus', columns=['TestPriority'],
                     aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

print(res)

TestPriority      3  4
AutomationStatus      
Automated         0  4
ManualTest        4  0
```